# Fresh install encrypted all my data

Tags: encryption

I was runing an old version of ubuntu (15.10) and I decided to perform a fresh install of the last LTS version 16.04. 
   Under 15.10, I had a user (rz) with all my personnal data. I installed the 16.04 with a different user (ryad). The new installer encrypted my home directory without giving me the change to refuse that.

Now my folder /home/rz is crypted, i cannot accèss it. All my personnal data is in there. and I have no idea how to fix it.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: That is really odd. I just did upgrades for 4 computers running 15.10 to 16.04 this week and none of them have been encrypted as a result. Did you encrypt the previous Home partition?

Comment: Can you still see yout old home files, do they take up about the same space? I've heard of fresh installs overwriting whole partitions before, one reason why a backup is vital before installing any OS